# How to force jQuery .load() method to use POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Why isn't my method posting data?
According to jquery docs: 
"Request Method

The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed."

```
var car = {{ car }}
var motorcycle = {{ motorcycle }}    
$('.send_data').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#'+container).load(
            $(this).attr('href'),
            { car: car, motorcycle: motorcycle },
            function(data) {
                $('#'+container).effect('highlight');
            }
        );
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [jQuery `.load` source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/load.js#L39) is straightforward:

```
} else if ( params && typeof params === "object" ) {
    type = "POST";
}
```

Unless `car` or `motorcycle` are [not being classified as objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof), a `POST` request should have been issued.

Comment: That is the jQuery source code, so you don't change it. You should check to see if `{ car: car, motorcycle: motorcycle }` is a `typeof` object. Presumably it is not since your method is not posting data.

Comment: Thanks, I had accidentally other value as non object

Comment: @thevangelist - No problem, glad you got it working!

Answer (score 7):

Use $.post() instead of $.load()

Answer (score 2):

Use `$.ajax()` and define `type: 'post'`.